# The structure of "the higher a mountain"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

What is the structure of "the higher a mountain" in the following sentence? And what does it mean?

As a general rule, **the higher a mountain** is, the more recently it was formed.

Comment: @Community. This question should be reopened. In my opinion, the answer that is linked to does not give an adequate response.

Comment: @BillJ - Then you should give that linked-to question what you feel is an “adequate" response.

Comment: @J.R. It was 6 years ago! Far too late for making a response. We should re-open this one.

Comment: @BillJ No such thing as "too late for a response" here on SE.  :-)  Plus it's better to have extra explanations all in one page if possible, instead of spreading it out into multiple links that may not be noticed.  Plus the OP seems to agree that the page in question had the information they needed.

Comment: @BillJ - We don’t re-open duplicates just because the originals are old. Anyone coming to this question will see the link to the previous question, and look for answers there. If you have something to add, that’s the right place to put it.